# single table to reduce joint queries?

Tags: mysql

We are doing e-commerce shopping site in PHP.

We designed database as below image.

we are planning to delete "category_Details" table and include **"category_id & category_name"** columns in **"products_information"** table as this going **reduce one table**. Is this good idea or is it better to have separate columns for "categories"? We may end up with 15 rows under "category_name" column.
We are planning to merge as we have to use multiple joint queries to fetch information?

In image designer_details table contains all sellers/vendors who sell their products.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a good idea to put the `category_name` in the `product_information`. This way you will 'break' the normalization. Instead of storing the `category_name` 15 times you store the same name multiple times. You speak about gaining on joining but this will give you, taken the limited number of rows in `category_details`, not much advantage. The whole `category_details` table will be in memory and you only need to join if you need the `category_name`.

You say that you have about 15 categories. I suppose that you have (many) more product. So this makes it a *one-to-many* relation which is the second case in the answer to [MySQL: multiple tables or one table with many columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774715/mysql-multiple-tables-or-one-table-with-many-columns) that you mentioned in a comment. There it mentions that in the case of a *one-to-many* relation you must put the information in separate tables.

Also look at the application level. If somebody has to enter each time a `category_name` you might end up with the same name but spelled different. This will make it hard to search on it.